# How do I use GitHub API for Java to get information about repositories and install GitHub Apps?

Tags: java, github, methods, jar, github-api

I'm trying to use Kohsuke's GitHub API for Java. I'm trying to connect to an Enterprise GH instance just to read some basic information about repos and, if possible, install GitHub Apps.

I'm a total beginner with Java. I've managed to add the JAR from the developer to my project and instantiate a few classes, but I can't figure out how to specify a URL for a repository to authenticate, much less get information or install an GitHub app through code.

Here is what I've put together so far, but functionally does nothing:

```
import org.kohsuke.github.GHAppInstallation;
import org.kohsuke.github.GitHub;
import org.kohsuke.github.GitHubBuilder;
import org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository;

public class appinstaller extends GHAppInstallation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.

        GitHub github = new GitHubBuilder().withPassword("name", "xyz").build();
        String name = new GHRepository().getFullName();
        GitHub github2 = GitHub.connect();

        GHRepository repo = github.getRepository()

//        GHRepository repo = github.createRepository(
//                "new-repository","this is my new repository",
//                "https://www.kohsuke.org/",true/*public*/);
//        repo.addCollaborators(github.getUser("abayer"),github.getUser("rtyler"));
//        repo.delete();
    }
}
```

There aren't any good reference examples for Java beginners in the API documentation (https://github-api.kohsuke.org/). Could somebody with some experience and know-how get me started on basic authentication to an existing repo?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to understand the API to its fullest? I have to use it as well for a project and I can't seem to warp my head around it.